# Are there any PHP frameworks that allow for e-commerce?

Tags: php, frameworks, e-commerce

I'm wondering what the recommended PHP frameworks are for building e-commerce sites with logins/checkouts/etc. The easier to understand and get up-and-running the better.

Answer (score 3):

[magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is a commercial ecommerce platform that's really nice.  there's also [zen cart](http://www.zen-cart.com/) and a plethora of open source ones.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to look at a CMS such as Drupal to get pre-built e-commerce functionality. A module such as Ubercart (http://www.ubercart.org/) will add this functionality to Drupal.

Comment: Interesting, I think I will look into this